# ModalPopupExtender and dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following code on my page:

```
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpLabelCheck" PopupControlID="pnlModal" TargetControlID="lstCategory" 
OkControlID="btnOK" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel id="pnlModal" CssClass="modalPopup" runat="server">
    <p>Please make sure all data is entered before continuing.</p>
    <p><asp:Button ID="btnOK" Text="OK" runat="server" /></p>
</asp:Panel>
```

The target control ID is a dropdownList. What happens is any interaction with the dropdownlist triggers the popup. I'd like to wait until the user makes a selection, then conditionally show the popup based on the result of another method.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: `then conditionally show the popup based on the result of another method.` What type of method (server-side or javascript function)?

Comment: I was thinking server-side. I need to run a check for records in a database then render (or not render) the modal popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dummy hidden control as target for extender and show it in server code with `Show` method call